# allowProvisioningUpdates not working in automatic signing fastlane

Tags: ios, github-actions, fastlane, building-github-actions, fastlane-pilot

I'm trying to upload build through Github action but i'm stuck in the last point. I'm trying to upload build through automatic signing. But every time got the error.

FastFile:-

```
platform :ios do
lane :closed_beta do
keychain_name = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER
keychain_password = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD
ensure_temp_keychain(keychain_name, keychain_password)

  api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
  key_id: APPLE_KEY_ID,
  issuer_id: APPLE_ISSUER_ID,
  key_content: "#{ENV["APPLE_KEY_CONTENT"]}".gsub('\n', '\\n'),
  is_key_content_base64:true,            
  duration: 1200,            
  in_house: false
  ) 

  increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "**********")

  enable_automatic_code_signing(
    team_id: "********",
  )

  gym(
  configuration: "Release",
  scheme: "*******",
  export_xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates",
  workspace: '********',
  include_bitcode: false,
  export_method: "app-store",
  export_options: {
  uploadBitcode: false,
    uploadSymbols: false,
    compileBitcode: false,
    provisioningProfiles: { 
        DEVELOPER_APP_ID => PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER
     },
        "signingStyle": "manual"
    }
  )

  pilot(
  apple_id: "*******",
  app_identifier: "*******",
  skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
  skip_submission: true,
  distribute_external: false,
  notify_external_testers: false,
  ipa: "./*******.ipa"
 )

  delete_temp_keychain(keychain_name)
 end
```

Xcode:-

[image]

I have tried with and without “-allowProvisioningUpdates”.

**With I get the following:**

> Code Signing Error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode
> Code Signing Error: No profiles for '[my app name]' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching '[my app name]'.

**Without I get:**

> No profiles for '[my app name]' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching '[my app name]'.
> Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile.
> To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.

Question: Can someone please explain to me how to solve this, I've tried with above code but no results yet.

Can someone please explain to me How to upload app test Flight with automatic signing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My biggest Mistake, i was not set the provisional profile in the build settings. Please update the same provisional profile in the build setting option.